# Cannot use GridbagLayout in JPanel inside another Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

So my issue is, I have my frame(BorderLayout) and three Jpanels (north, center, south).
The JPanel on the center(BorderLayout) has two Jpanels (north, south).

The Panel on the south(GridBagLayout), gives me this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)", on line 44.

This is what happens without line 44 and 47 (image attached):[image]

What I want on that JPanel for testing purposes (for now) is to add 2 buttons, but I get the error mentioned above.

The code beneath relates to the center panel of the frame, mentioned above:

```
package com.system.reservation.airline.panels;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BodyPanel extends JPanel {
    JLabel login_label;
    public BodyPanel(){
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //------------ Login Panel ------------------------
        JPanel login_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        login_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        login_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 5));

        login_label = new JLabel();
        login_label.setText("Login");
        login_label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        login_label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        login_panel.add(login_label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //------------ Login Panel ------------------------

        //------------ Input Panel ------------------------
        JPanel input_fields_panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        input_fields_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        input_fields_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 5));

        Button btn1 = new Button("Btn 1");
        Button btn2 = new Button("Btn 2");
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        this.add(btn1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        this.add(btn2, gbc);
        //------------ Input Panel ------------------------

        this.add(login_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(input_fields_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Edit: I thought the post would show the number of lines.

```
Line 44: this.add(btn1, gbc);
Line 47: this.add(btn2, gbc);
```

Sorry for that!

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: The layout manager for your BodyPanel class is a BorderLayout. So you can't use a GridBagConstraint. You need to add your components to the "InputFieldsPanel", since that is the panel using the GridBagLayout. Also, don't use Button, that is an AWT component. For Swing use `JButton`.

Comment: Ok, @camickr, that makes sense to me.
But what do you mean by "add"?
Is it creating a new class,  use "extends JButton", and  then creating an instance of that class, for example: "LoginButton loginButton = new LoginButton", so I can add it;

Or what did you have in mind?

Comment: No, just create as many instances of `JButton` as you need buttons.  Use Swing components, don't extend them, unless you intend to override one or more of the class methods.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: *But what do you mean by "add"?* - you invoke the add(...) method on the appropriate panel as I described.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I figured it out, I was adding to the BodyPanel instead of the input_fields_panel.
Just replaced "this.add(btn1, gbc);" to "input_fields_panel.add(btn1, gbc);", and it worked.
Thanks once more!